# WPF Circular Animation that Mimics current Canvas

Tags: wpf, animation, canvas

I'm implementing a graphical animation in wpf with a circular animation in reference to the attached picture (Obviously I'm no artist...).  The square represents the visible form while the entire image represents a canvas which translates from page to page.  The animation scrolls and wraps over from 1->2->3->4->1 in the right direction and 4->3->2->1->4 in the left direction.

As you can see my previous implementation from the colored arrows in the picture allows me to use a front and back porch that is identical to the needed picture.  When the animation moves to the front or back picture, an instantaneous animation is used to move quickly to the real page without the user knowing.

So far this has worked good and is very smooth.  The problem lies in that my implementation is not just simple images.  Each page will have complex animations itself.  Using the same implementation I would have to mirror every single animation in the 4 real pages as I would have to in the end pages that exist only for a smooth animation to roll over.

Obviously this would be very wasteful and non ideal for many reasons...

A thought I had would be to create an Image from the front page 1 and 4 and overlay that image over the front and back porch by using another canvas.  But this still seems like its too difficult and there should be an easier way.

Is there a preferred or easier method than this?  I'm looking for some kind of canvas that mimics the other canvas so that I don't have to worry about this. Either that or an entire new algorithm to wrap over the end pages.

I've looked around the internet for this scroll routine and haven't found anything yet.  Thank you for any help!  Sorry for the long post.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer to my question by using a VisualBrush and binding it to the canvas.

```
    <Canvas Name="backgroundCanvas" Visibility="Visible"  Height="{StaticResource animHeight}" Width="6144">

        <Canvas Name="menuFrontCanvas" Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="{StaticResource animHeight}" Width="{StaticResource animWidth}">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{StaticResource animWidth}" Height="{StaticResource animHeight}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=menu4Canvas}" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas Name="menu1Canvas"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="1024,0,0,0" Height="{StaticResource animHeight}" Width="{StaticResource animWidth}">
            <Image Name="alpsLogoImage" Canvas.ZIndex="99"  Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible" 
                IsEnabled="True" StretchDirection="Both" Source="WPFResources/ALPSLogo.png" />
            <Image Name="menu1Image" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                IsEnabled="True" StretchDirection="Both" Source="WPFResources/Backgrounds/menu1Image.png" />
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas Name="menu2Canvas" Visibility="Visible" Margin="2048,0,0,0" Height="{StaticResource animHeight}" Width="{StaticResource animWidth}">
            <Image Name="menu2Image" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                IsEnabled="True" StretchDirection="Both" Source="WPFResources/Backgrounds/menu2Image.png" />
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas Name="menu3Canvas" Visibility="Visible" Margin="3072,0,0,0" Height="{StaticResource animHeight}" Width="{StaticResource animWidth}">
            <Image Name="menu3Image" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                IsEnabled="True" StretchDirection="Both" Source="WPFResources/Backgrounds/menu3Image.png" />
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas Name="menu4Canvas" Visibility="Visible" Margin="4096,0,0,0" Height="{StaticResource animHeight}" Width="{StaticResource animWidth}">
            <Image Name="menu4Image" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                IsEnabled="True" StretchDirection="Both" Source="WPFResources/Backgrounds/menu4Image.png" />  
        </Canvas>

        <Canvas Name="menuBackCanvas" Visibility="Visible"   Margin="5120,0,0,0" Height="{StaticResource animHeight}" Width="{StaticResource animWidth}">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{StaticResource animWidth}" Height="{StaticResource animHeight}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=menu1Canvas}" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>

    </Canvas>
```